# Cannot seem to use GetType with Activator.CreateInstance

Tags: c#, reflection, gettype

I am trying to get an object using Reflection, and then launch a method on that object.  I was getting null from `Type.GetType("my.namespace.item")` so I decided to try a test that SHOULD work.  Using this code `Type.GetType((new my.namespace.item()).GetType().FullName)` I still get null.

That should not happen from what I understand.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show the function you are working on and indicate the line at which you are getting an exception (NullReferenceException?), if any?

Comment: @Jay : I am specifically getting a NullReferenceException at Type.GetType(), which is why that was the only code I included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only specifying the `FullName` of the `Type`, which is (ironically) not the full name you need. `Type.GetType(string)` requires the `AssemblyQualifiedName` of the `Type` in order to work:

```
Type.GetType((new my.namespace.item()).GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName)
```

should be fine. Specifying it manually would look like:

```
Type.GetType("Namespace.TypeName, MyAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b17a5c561934e089");
```

Obviously you can omit the Version, Culture, or PublicKeyToken if they don't apply.

Comment: How can I get the AssemblyQualifiedName if I don't have the type?  The Type is being stored in the Database and therefore I won't know that I specifically need a `new my.namespace.item()`.  Also, I can't store the Version, Culure and PublicKeyToken as they may change.

Comment: Use Assembly.GetTypes() and match up to the name out of the db. If there are multiple assemblies add assembly name to the db as well. Or Create a custom attribute and decorate the types you wish to expose. where the customer attribute has a property that is the name used in the db.

Comment: I just changed my database field from "my.namespace.thing" to "my.namespace.thing, my.namespace".  This works.